# Ebean - Not all records are returned

Tags: java, orm, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I am totally new in the world of the [Ebean](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/documentation.html) ORM persistence layer used in Play Framework 2. My initial impression is really good but in my hobby project I stumbled on the issue I don't know how to solve. I am not sure whether there is something I did wrong (models?) or maybe it's just lack of my knowledge on Ebean.

I have two models: `User` and `UserAccount`:

- `User` may or may not have an account.
- `UserAccount` always points to exactly one `User`.

So there is `User` model:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private UserAccount userAccount;

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<>(
        Long.class, User.class
    );

    // ... Getters and Setters ...
}
```

and there is `UserAccount` model:

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public static Finder<Long, UserAccount> find = new Finder<>(
        Long.class, UserAccount.class
    );

    // ... Getters and Setters ...
}
```

What I would like to do is to fetch all users with and without accounts.

I was sure that this piece of code will do the job:

```
User.find.all();
```

... but on my surprise only users that had an associated account record were returned.

Another interesting thing is that this call:

```
User.find.findRowCount();
```

... returned the actual number of users with and without accounts so it works like I was expecting both of those queries to work.

So what am I missing there? Is there anything wrong with my models? Why not all users are returned?

**[EDIT]**

I am attaching a little bit more info.

---

Executed SQL for:

```
User.find.findRowCount();
```

is:

```
select count(*) from user t0
```

---

Executed SQL for:

```
User.find.all();
```

is

```
select t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t0.surname c2, t1.id c3 from user t0 join user_account t1 on t1.user_id = t0.id
```

---

It looks to me that inner join is used instead of left join. What is reason for this?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is yet, but if what you have here is exactly what you have in your project, it seems like your UserAccount class is incorrect. Trying changing User.class to UserAccount.class in your UserAccount class.

Comment: It was just mistake I made when writing a question. Thanks for pointing this out anyway (I edited the question).

Answer (score 0):

In your *User* class you use **mappedBy = "user"** for the column name although in *UserAccount* class you use **name = "user_id"**.